# iis 7 url rewrite with preset paths

Tags: url, iis-7, url-rewriting

I'm trying to make something like this work in iis 7, or web config

request:
`products.aspx?id=100`

rewrite:
`domain/products/mp3`

Please note, I do not want redirection, for `domain/products/mp3` is invalid path, I just want the url rewrite so the user sees this path but the server serves the actual request.

Can you help?

Answer (score 0):

Can you use the URL Rewrite functionality from ASP.NET instead? That was built for that.

```
 RouteTable.Routes.MapPageRoute("Test", "domain/products/{type}", "~/products.aspx");
```

Then in products.aspx you have to map from mp3 to 100 somehow, but I assume you have a db table for that anyway.

Comment: that must be asp.net 4.0. I'm using 3.5. Is there an equivalent?

Comment: Sounds like it's supported since 3.5
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.routing.routetable(v=VS.90).aspx